# Add Version Info into .rc file in Qt

Tags: qt, resources, window, version, versioninfo

I've got a `myprogramm.exe.manifest`file and `myprogramm.rc` resource file respectively. When I add to  resource file (where there is a `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "myprogramm.exe.manifest"` that sees the path of manifest) Version Info it can't see manifest file and shows an error: "debug/myprogramm_res.0" couldn't find. How can I add version info? So that I could see both manifest and version info.
PS I added in .pro file `RC_FILE = myprogramm.rc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out my own mistake. `*.rc` resource file is actually captious to any little punctuations and syntaxes. So that I found this [here](http://blog.strixcode.com/2010/08/embedding-application-manifest-and.html) informing and actually right approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add manifest to project use it like this

```
win32 {
RC_FILE     = c:/app.rc
-manifest c:/app.exe.manifest
}
```

or don't use full path if it on project home dir.

Answer (score 0):

Add in you *.pro file:

```
VERSION = 1.2.3
```

Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#version). For adding version to executable you do not need *.rc file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already figured out to embed version info to executable and posted that answer. More answers are good, thanks.